# Python Client Socket and Server

Tags: python, sockets, select, client, raw-input

Hi i'm working with socket to understand and in future adding socket in a my bigger program... i've created a simply server with socket and select module:

```
import socket,select

#Costanti:
HOST="0.0.0.0"
PORT=9999
#Lista Client:
Lista_client=[]
#Inizializzazione server
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))
print "Server started on port",PORT,"........"
server.listen(10)
Lista_client.append(server)
#Loop
while True:
    pronti,scrivibili,errori=select.select(Lista_client,[],[])
    for sock in pronti:
        #nuova connessione:
        if sock == server:
            client,addr=server.accept()
            Lista_client.append(client)
            sock.send("Il Client",addr,"e connesso")
        else :
            try:
                data=sock.recv(5126)
                if data :
                    print addr,":",data
                    for x in pronti: x.send(addr,"Ha inviato:",data)
            except:
                addr_ex=addr
                sock.close()
                Lista_client.remove(sock)
                for x in Lista_server: x.send(addr_ex,"e uscito dal SERVER")
                print addr_ex, " uscito dal server"
```

It work fine...
my question is:
How i can write a Client that write and recive simultaneusly ... because if a create a client with what i know,it will block with raw_input function and then recive

Thanks

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: no i' using window... why?

Comment: For windows, if you want non-blocking input from console; you're restricted to using `msvcrt` module. Unix systems, otoh, already support non-blocking input from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: i' ve tried with stdin... are you sure thet with window don't work?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I researched for the same a few months ago. I ended up using pygame for the same (since I wanted a cross-platform solution).

Comment: thanks very much! I looked mvcrt module... it is for the keyboard input true? how i can implement?